# Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Response has no Location header for redirect | Flutter

Tags: flutter, http, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I'am doing a http get request but i getting this error `Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Response has no Location header for redirect`. This is my code.

```
Future checkForUpdates() async {
    var url = "$baseUrl/api/auth/apiversion";
    var response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse(url),
      headers: {
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "version": "1.0.0",
      },
    );
    print(response.body);
  }
```

Comment: Care to share the request and response you are getting?

Comment: This issue is because of the status code from the api. After changing the status code from api it works. The status code from api is 301. This is for permanent redirecting.